# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor: Include JavaScript file in the head tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, include, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to figure out the proper Razor syntax to get a JavaScript file for a particular *.cshtml to be in the head tag along with all the other include files that are defined in _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: You should also consider putting the js at the bottom of the page instead of in the head section.

Comment: Only issue I found with the sample code is that the @section "JavaScript" need not be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: One more thing: if this is a JavaScript tag, be careful about the usage, I needed to use the END Tag of the script element to get this to run correctly. <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/RDA.js")"></script>;

Comment: @Mattias Jakobsson - Not always.  That depends on a specific case.

Comment: @Dimskiy if you'll allow me to be a word parser and pedant, you should indeed always CONSIDER putting the js at the bottom, whether you actually place it there or not.

Answer (score 411, accepted):

You can use **[Named Sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx).**

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")"></script>
    @RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
</head>
```

**_SomeView.cshtml**

```
@section JavaScript
{
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/SomeScript.js")"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/AnotherScript.js")"></script>
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking at WebPageBase and had guessed that that might be the answer, but didn't quite know the proper syntax. Can you recommended a reference guide for the MVC 3? Regards..

Comment: Ha! I WISH there was a reference guide to both MVC 3 and Razor syntax. I got the above from the Gu's blog. The best reference for MVC 3 is probably the release notes.

Comment: Oh and good tip w.r.t. the close tag for the `<script>` tag - didn't know that (haven't tried named sections with JS yet). now i (and others) will know

Comment: No quotes around the "JavaScript" after the @section, otherwise solid answer thank you :0)

Comment: FYI: Javascript should be rendered right before the `</body>` tag instead of in the head tag. This is so that it wouldn't prevent parallel downloads by the browser. See http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: @Peter - yes, i know - but i was simply addressing the answer (JS in head tag).

Comment: What about CSS files (I realize this wasn't brought-up in the original question, but it's related).

Comment: @WEFX - same technique. "JavaScript" is just a section name. Can be anything, so you could create a "Css" section, and render out `<link>` tags.

Comment: One last tweak: `src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/SomeScript.js")"` should be `src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/SomeScript.js")'`.  i.e. Change the outer double quotes to singles to ensure it's syntactically correct, and use a tilde so the URL will be correctly mapped if using virtual directories (thus justifying the use of the URL.Content method).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Stephen Patten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4311876/1836461)s answer, and to completely change my previous version of this answer:

You can add the `@RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)` line pretty much anywhere in the file. Meaning, it doesn't have to be in the `head` or even the `footer` tag. In the code I'm looking at for work, it's in a `div`.

Also, you have to put this line into any `.cshtml` file that's a parent of a partial containing scripts. This allows for nesting partials with scripts, and without having to include all the scripting in the original parent or child. Saying it differently, simply having the `RenderSection` code in the "layout" or original parent file doesn't automatically cascade to nested partials.

The caveat to this is that your scripts will be scattered throughout the resulting HTML file rendered for the browser. This can lead to debugging difficulties, including accidentally having multiple script methods with the same name or including the same external scripts multiple times.