# Razor page lifecycle in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pipeline

My question in general about render pipeline, i have seen ASP.NET MVC pipeline scheme and there was a step called View Engine, so how it works? I want to know about this scenarios:

- What is rendered first, master page or view?
- If i use `Response.End()` in `@{}` block at the start of page does this interupt execution of page and stops render of the view?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What is rendered first, master page or view?

The view. The parser starts from the Layout and builds a LIFO (Last In First Out) structure recursing down to child views and partials. Once the LIFO is ready it starts popping out and processing the elements. This means that inner-most partials/views will be processed before the layout and the last one to be processed is the Layout itself.

> If i use Response.End() in @{} block at the start of page does this
>   interupt execution of page and stops render of the view?

Using `Response.End` in any view will cause a completely blank page being rendered. Never use in any view. `Response.End` basically aborts the current thread by triggering a `ThreadAbortException` which is not something that you want to do in your Razor views.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Steve Sanderson's [Request-Handling Pipeline Poster](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/10/08/aspnet-mvc-learning-resource-request-handling-pipeline-poster/). It explains the whole request process quite in detail. It's from MVC version 1.0, but it's still valid. Just replace 'WebForm' with Razor.

It really shouldn't bother you whether the master or the view is rendered first. Could you explain why this matters to you?

Comment: sometimes good to know how things works, it helps to understand why it works like this and not other way :)

Comment: I can demonstrate a reason this knowledge is good. I've been using cassette for bundling in my project. It has static methods for "including" resource bundles in the page. A code block like `@{  Bundles.Reference("~/bundle/pageScripts", "Head");}` in a child view would get executed first and if it's dependent on jquery which is defined in the layout, the layout's code will execute after the child views, which will result in incorrect ordering of the script files. There are a number of ways to fix this, but it helps to know why the calls are happening in that order.

Comment: The reason @JonathanTech gives is the reason I needed to know this as well -- only I'm using MVC4's System.Web.Optimization instead of Cassette. Same idea though.