# RenderSection not working inside Partial View in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

In my ASP.NET MVC3 project I have a standard `_Layout.cshtml` generated by Visual Studio 2010 and after closing my `<body>` tag, I place a `RenderSection`:

_Layout.cshtml:

```
</body>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@RenderSection("ScriptContent", required: false)
</html>
```

Then in my `Index.cshtml` View I have:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.MyViewModel
@{ Html.RenderPartial("MyPartial", Model);  }
```

If I place the `@section ScriptContent` in the Index.cshtml it displays correctly. If I place it in my Partial View `MyPartial.cshtml`:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.MyViewModel

@section ScriptContent {
     <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Filters.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
}
```

In my page source I have:

```
</body>
     <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</html>
```

Meaning the `@section` is not executed. What might be the cause? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render a Section in a Partial View in MVC3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764936/how-to-render-a-section-in-a-partial-view-in-mvc3)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not possible to set an `@section` in the layout from a partial view. As a workaround you could instead call an action which renders the necessary `<script>` and HTML - although this is not very elegant.

Comment: thansk! Therefore the only possible solution, besides the one you propose, is to move the @section within my View