# Working with a separate js file in asp.net mvc application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am creating an asp.net MVC application. 
I want to separate my js code from the razor code in view.
So I've got a file with the path "~/Scripts/SearchProductsScript.js"
_Layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")"></script>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("JavaScript"))
    {
        @RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
    }
  ...
</head>
```

_SomeView.cshtml:

```
@section JavaScript
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/SearchProductsScript.js")"></script>
}
```

And SearchProductsScript.js:

```
var uri;

function test() {
    alert("TEST");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    Doing something here
    $(':radio').change(function () {
        Doing something here
    });
});
```

I'm not sure how to properly use this separate js file. None of the functions is working and trying to call them from the _SomeView.cshtml doesn't work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { test(); });
</script>
```

or

```
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="test();" />
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the development console in your browser, as you seem to have an extra `});` in your SearchProductsScript that has no business being there. May just be a mistake from where you've copied it to SO

Comment: oh I didn't remove it while deleting the code  but this is not the issue

Comment: I get an error that the function is not defined

Comment: Check in console sources that your external javascript is loaded or not if not than it might be js path issue

Comment: It seems to me that is is not loaded

Comment: when I added a string 
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/SearchProductsScript.js")
to Layout.cshtml the script was called!

Answer (score 1):

So reason the js code was not called was that I was trying to set a section from the partial view which is not possible. 
[RenderSection not working inside Partial View in ASP.NET MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953258/rendersection-not-working-inside-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc3)