# MVC @Html.Action() rendering Partial View after _Layout?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC3 solution, I am attempting to implement the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765578/1026567) to dynamically add a CSS reference to the _Layout.cshtml file from within a partial view.

Here is a snippet of my _Layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

@Html.RenderStyles()

</head>

<body>
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        @Html.Action("Header", "Shared")
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>

</html>
```

and in the partial view (that is rendered by the @Html.Action("Header", "Shared") bit):

```
@{
    Html.AddStyle(Model.Company.CSSPath);
}
```

While the HtmlExtension methods are working as expected, it seems that the events are occuring in the incorrect order.

The  @Html.RenderStyles() in the _Layout head is occuring before the Partial View has time to add the CSS file to the Styles. I was under the impression that Partial Views were rendered before the _Layout.

I'm guessing that the cause has to do with the fact that I'm rendering my Partial View with an Html.Action call. If I don't do so, however, then how can I populate the Partial view with its desired model?

---

Per Matt Razza's comment, if I were to render the partial view the "normal way" using:
    @Html.Partial("ViewName", model)
I'm then required to give my _Layout a Model and then force all other models to inherit from that Model? Is that truly the best option?

Comment: Don't you want `@Html.Partial("ViewName", model)`? I don't understand why you're using `Action`.

Comment: Because my _Layout has a different model than the partial view. I'm not sure what merging the models will do to the application, but it's certainly a possibility. I will let you know

Comment: When I add a model to my _Layout view and render the header in that way, it then requires that all of my models are of that same type (which is not realistic at all)

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to have an instance of the partial view model as a member of the parent model? `@Html.Partial("ViewName", model.PartialModel)`

Comment: @MattRazza, I could do that. The only problem with that is that every one of my models in the entire application would have to contain that partial model. Yes, I could force them to extend some sort of base model class. But what happens when someone adds a model to the application without extending the base class? Or, what happens if the data for that partial model doesn't get populated completely from within that model?

Comment: The point is that it seems like a lot of work (and a lot of added complication) just for a dynamic CSS file.