# Hosting javascript in a view rather than a .js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

- I have a partial view which contains javascript specific only to said view
- Apparently, ASP.NET MVC does not support sections in partial views, so I cannot add a script section to my partial to be added to the end of my layout page
- I came upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764936/how-to-render-a-section-in-a-partial-view-in-mvc3) which proposes a promising-looking set of extensions, but it requires that I put the javascript in a separate .js file.
- So I did that only to find that the Razor syntax in the original javascript won't work there.
- I then happened upon a VS plugin called RazorJS, but it doesn't appear to have been updated since 2011, so I am not even going to give it a go.

So it appears my only option is to host my javascript in a view, but I need to be able to inject it into the view from a partial view.  Any way to do this?

Comment: Let's make sure I understand this - you want your javascript to be rendered by Razor, correct? So you can do something like this I assume: `var myVal = '@Model.MyVal';

Comment: @MattSpinks That's basically it, yes, but I have to be able to do this in a separate .js file

Comment: There is no way to render anything from Razor into a separate javascript file (at-least not without a plugin). What is commonly done, however, is to set variables' values within your main view page, and then in your separate javascript file, consume those variables/values via parameters.

Comment: Why does the js "have to be" in a `@section` (of partial)? If it seems to be specific to it(?). Can the script be "cut up" - e.g. create an object that's dependent on some `model` on the Partial, and the "rest" of the script (the logic that works with the `object) separately?

Comment: @MattSpinks That is actually what I ended up doing as a work-around (declared the js variable in my layout before the other scripts were loaded).  It works, but now I have stuff in my layout page that only applies to certain views, so I want to get it out of there if at all possible

Comment: @EdSF I have a "script" section at the bottom of my layout.  From within my partial, I want to be able to tell the parser that I have scripts pertenant to this partial, but want them loaded at the very end of the rendered document.

Comment: Ok so, the "functional" part of the script can be in the `@section` of the container `view` (so that gets "restricted" to the `view` that uses the `partial` and renders in the right place), and the "data" part of the script that depends on some `model` goes with the `partial`. Does that work?

Comment: Scripts should never be in partials. Apart from the fact they will be rendered in line, you risk rendering duplicates. Put the script in the main view of layout.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to **render** anything from Razor into a separate javascript file  (at-least not without a plugin). What is commonly done, however, is to set variables' values within your main view page, and then in your separate javascript file, consume those variables/values via parameters.

For example...

View:

```
<html>
<body>
...
  <button onclick='myFunction("@Model.MyVal");'>Click Here!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file:

```
function myFunction(myClickedVal) {
  alert(myClickedVal);
}
```

You could also use the same concept and use global variables. But do so at your own risk.