# How to add link to JavaScript file into the header of the certain ASP .NET MVC page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

How to add link to JavaScript file into the header of the certain ASP .NET MVC page?

Lets say there are _Layout.cshtml and About.cshtml and I need to put some javascript file  to the header of the About.cshtml. I mean to that page only.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=636

How it can be done?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110028/add-css-or-js-files-to-layout-head-from-views-or-partial-views

Comment: I personally think that the second answer on that link is better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


    @if (IsSectionDefined("AddToHead"))
    {
         @RenderSection("AddToHead", required: false)
    }    
</head>
```

**About.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";     
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@section footer {
     <b>Footer Here</b>
}

@section AddToHead {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/test.js")" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
}
```

Comment: I think you don't need to verify if section defined when you don't have `else` part (default content)

Comment: You should at least give credit to the author of this approach that you adapted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7357102/1026459

Comment: @user636525 I am sure It will.

Answer (score 4):

Why must it be in the header? You can include any script you need inline:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't work if the script is not in the header... Some of JQuery plugins are not working I mean.

Comment: @Peretz - Never that I have come across, can you provide a working example of that happening?

Comment: @TravisJ Situation I just came across at work. cshtml files were including js files. When the section was reloaded via json, there was a bunch of global variables (working on getting rid of those) that were getting mauled because of the reload. So there's one example.

Comment: @Tom - Usually people prevent that by checking for existence before initialization. For example `var myInitializer = myInitializer || init();`. I think my previous comment was probably poorly worded, in that order can definitely affect the script, however it will still *load*.

Comment: Which is what I did to fix our issue (added the OR), but it's still a case where this applies. Working on an application with a lot of those types of variables. Having said that, I now realize that this post is 2 years old. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
HtmlGenericControl my_js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            my_js.Attributes["async"] = "async";
            my_js.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
            my_js.Attributes["src"] = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js";
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(my_js);
```

You need to use namespace : "using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" to use HtmlGenericControl.