# When I have to use @section scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

[image]

My current structure has a layout with header, body and footer. Inside the body load a view using ajax to call for a action controller returning a Json and painting a tree view. When user click on the tree view the footer should load the detailed information. But isnt working, my guess is because the scripts section isnt render properly.

Right now the script are in the layout without bundles or anything and work ok on the Main body because I use Jquery and a Tree to load the Json data.

But in the partial View get an error. I could write a `@section scripts` area and copy all the script from the layout in the Partial View but why should I duplicate the code?

[image]

The worst part is only give me problem in the production enviroment ... on my devolpment enviroment works ok.

[image]

So the questions:

- Why the main view can see the scripts define on the Layout but the Partial View Doesnt?
- Why my development enviroment work ok, but productions doesnt?
- What should I do to solve this?

EDIT: More testing.

This is a test View, this render in the Body. But I need include script section otherwise the dialog doesnt show, even when layout have the scripts too.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TreeDetails";    
}
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>TEST PAGE</h2>

    <script>

        // Your code goes here.
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("before dialog");
            $("#dialog").dialog();
            console.log("after dialog");
        })
    </script>

    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

@section scripts {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: Do you have your `treeview` script loaded also within the Layout? is that done with the `@scripts` section or just with a regular `<script>` tag? In my experience with Sections in mvc is just a content that would be replaced by what is in the partials. However, you need to be careful to since `js` loading is sequential (loaded as the page reference them)... so in the final HTML, if your `treeview` script is rendered after you are actually using it... you will get this error. Try moving your @scripts section declaration or loading your script within the main layout. Can you post some code?

Comment: @DavidEspino I dont have @script section yet. I only have script tags in the head section of my layout, there include the jquery.js. Body View have a script loading the tree view, but `jstree.js` is also declared in the Layout. Foot section have some jquery.tabs, and there is where is failing.

Comment: Ok more info... when the error occurs? Is it on load? whenever you click something?... can you paste the order on how your scripts are rendered? it seems that `dialog` is undefined maybe a `jquery.ui` function? is that already declared on the output html when you load your page?

Comment: @DavidEspino I include a View sample. Here I need include the script.section otherwise the dialog doesnt show. This render direct into the Body, not using PartialView.

Comment: Can you try moving those scripts on your @section scripts to the layout as regular `<script>` I believe that your @scripts section are rendered after the @body in the layout. You don't want to use this sections to use base scripts like `jquery ui`, usually this section is used to inject the behavior for the current partial. For example... your view is TreeDetails.cshtml and you have a very specific client script behavior called `treedetails.js`. That is a good candidate for the @scripts section.

Comment: @DavidEspino All my scrips are inside the head tags of the Layout. Only at the end there are `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required:false)`

Comment: If you know a tutorial about this I will take it :(

Comment: I think the only thing you require is move the jquery scripts to your layout as a regular `<script>` tag, that should load your script dependencies in order. Heres a good example on how to use the `scripts section` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284707/how-to-add-script-src-inside-a-view-when-using-layout

Answer (score 0):

It seems a run time error due to an unrecognized jquery function.. try to move your link reference to jquery from your view @section area in the layout header..