# Can the scripts on the layout propagate to the views?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, layout

Im having problem with the scripts on the **[layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933047/when-i-have-to-use-section-scripts?noredirect=1#comment63317737_37933047)**, so I go to the basic to try understand what is doing the `@RenderSection("scripts",` and now I make it work.

But can I put the Jquery / Jquery.UI (js/css) in the Layout, so I dont have to put it on every view? because I try puting inside the head tag on the Layout and the view didnt saw it.

Here is my layout.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Layout</h1>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And my View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TreeDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutTest.cshtml";
}
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>TEST PAGE</h2>

    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>
    <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>

</body>
</html>

@section scripts {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        // Your code goes here.
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("before dialog");
            $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
            console.log("after dialog");

            $("#opener").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Move the `@RenderSection(...)` to immediately before the closing `</body>` tag. Note also that your css file should be in a separate `@RenderSection("styles", required: false)` inside the `<head>` tags. And it also looks like your repeating `jquery.js`using `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in the layout and again by including it inside `@section scripts {`

Comment: @StephenMuecke So, if I declare all my scripts/css in the `head` for the layout then I dont need the `@Scripts.Render(..)`  lines?

Comment: Yes you should still have them (to add the view specific scripts etc). But its recommended that `@RenderSection("styles", false)` goes in the `<head>` and `@RenderSection("styles", false)` goes immediately before the closing `</body>` tag (at the moment you have them outside the document)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Im still lost. Can you edit my view/layout and show me how should go? I found removing the jquery from the view make thing better, But still seem weird. Because the jquery.ui is still on the view. And i havent go with the styles yet.

Comment: You also have other issues such as your view should not have `<head>` tags etc. Give me 30 min and then I'll add a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code, including rendering the scripts outside the document, duplicating scripts, including css files in the scripts sections and duplicating `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags in the view.

The basic structure for the layout should be

```cs
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    ....
    // Add style sheets common to all views using this layout
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    // Add the place holder for any view specific css files
    @RenderSection("styles", required: false)
    // Include modernizr
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Layout</h1>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    // Add js files common to all views using this layout
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    // Add the place holder for any view specific js files
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

and for the view

```cs
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TreeDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutTest.cshtml";
}
<h2>TEST PAGE</h2>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>

// View specific style sheets
@section styles {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
}

// View specific scripts
@section scripts {
    // Note: don't repeat jquery-{version}.js
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log("before dialog");
        $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        console.log("after dialog");
        $("#opener").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        })
    </script>
}
```

Note: the use of `$(document).ready(function () {` is not strictly necessary in this case because the scripts are rendered immediately before the closing `</body>` tag, but if you were to move `@Scripts.Render(...)` and `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` into the `<head>` tags of the layout, then it would be required.

Comment: Why are two `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` or maybe the first one is `styles`?? and why `modernizr` is on the `head` and not at the end?

Comment: Oops, sorry, the top one should be `@RenderSection("styles", required: false)`, and `modernizr` must always be in the `<head>` for it to work.

Comment: Very good ... now I see the difference between Layout scripts and View scripts. But I still dont understand the bundles. Can I use `<script>` tag instead and should work the same, isnt?

Comment: Bundles are preferred - you get better performance, caching and automatic minimization of the files in release mode, but you can use `<script src="..."></script>` if you want to.

Comment: Yes, I know bundles have better performance, but first I need to make it work. When I have the correct script list I will investigate how make the buddles. Thanks

Comment: any sugestion on how script works with partial views? Im having trouble because if I want test a view it alone I include all the script, and when I add it as a partial view the scripts doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. Scripts should never be in partial views.