# How to Render Actual Script of JavaScript inside a View .Net Core

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, view, render

assuming i have script.js as:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        do something
    }
```

and my view is:

```
    <p> Hello </p>

    @section scripts{   
        @{await (some html help tag Load script.js)}
    }
```

i want it to be rendered as this output:

```
        <p> Hello </p>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           do something
        }
    </script>
```

Is there any razor or HTML helper that output the actual java script into the view?

Comment: don't use `@scripts`.  just drop the `script` tag right where you want it then.  Literally use the code in your last snippet.  `@scripts` renders the script wherever the `RenderSection` says

Comment: I want to keep the JavaScript file separate from the HTML code, but the result should be one HTML file, that's my point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

While there are several alternatives for separating JavaScript files from views, e.g.:

- [including the JavaScript as script src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284707/how-to-add-script-src-inside-a-view-when-using-layout)
- [inluding the JavaScript files in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

you could include JavaScript files as requested with the help of [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8) and [IHostingEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-2.2), e.g.:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env
...
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(env.WebRootPath + "/js/site.js"))
```