# Redirect to Home page after 5 seconds of inactivity on privacy page in .NET Core MVC using sessions

Tags: c#, .net, session, model-view-controller, session-state

I want that if anyone goes to any other page other than "Home" page and the user is inactive for 5 seconds then the user is redirected to the Home page in .NET Core MVC using Sessions

Comment: does this answer your Q? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript

Comment: No, because this is in Javascript and I need the solution in .Net CoreMVC

Comment: It doesn't make a difference which back-end you use, you should redirect the user from the front-end js when it stands idle for more then 5 seconds. why should you do it through the back end...

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: you need to add a section with a script in your view and add the js code there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284707/how-to-add-script-src-inside-a-view-when-using-layout

Comment: Still don't understand

Comment: in MVC there are cshtml files which are called views (razor pages), i.e. Home, or Privacy. in these pages you can add js code, and this code will run on the client not in your server, so in that client js you should write your code to redirect

Comment: Let's suppose I want that when a user is inactive on the "Privacy" page for 5 seconds, so I would add the following code at the end of "Privacy.cshtml"?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    var idleTime = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Increment the idle time counter every minute.
        var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 500); // 1 minute

        // Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
        $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
        $(this).keypress(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
    });

Comment: function timerIncrement() {
        idleTime = idleTime + 1;
        if (idleTime > 1) { // 20 minutes
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
</script>

Comment: yes but you have to change the js code it should actually redirect

Comment: How cann that be done?

Comment: `window.location.replace("http://www.redirect-here.com");`