# How to add conditional css in ejs layout

Tags: html, css, ejs

I have ejs layout like this on my `views/layout.ejs`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<%- body %> 
</body>
</html>
```

Then, on my `views/login/login.ejs` I have.

```
<h1 class="login">Login</h1>
```

I'm trying to link css file with my `login.ejs` file, but how I do that?
I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110028/add-css-or-javascript-files-to-layout-head-from-views-or-partial-views#7357102), It says that we should use conditional statement in `layout.ejs` but I don't really understand since it's wrote in asp language.

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally add CSS, you simple use plain JavaScript within EJS tags:

```
<head>
   <title>title</title>
   <% if (condition) { %>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/main.css">
   <% } %>
</head>
```

`/path/to/main.css` is resolved by your server, not EJS. `condition` can be anything JavaScript can do. For example:

```
<% if (path === '/login') %>
```

Comment: Why a downvote? External CSS can only be imported in the HTML document meta-data (header).