# MVC3 Razor - Adding JavaScript and CSS files to document head

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, include

I've used this before but i've forgotten the name of the method. I'm guessing it must be exclusive to MVC3/Razor. Is there a method that allows you to include a JavaScript or CSS file and then specify that it should be in the head. I remember it as two different methods similar to the following

```
IncludeJS("my.js").AtHead();
IncludeCSS("my.css").AtHead();
```

They might be HTML helpers but I can't find any reference to them anywhere.  Am I going mad?

Comment: Why not just put it into the _Layout.cshtml file? with the rest of your script/css includes?

Comment: What you're talking about sounds like a custom helper similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110028/add-css-or-js-files-to-layout-head-from-views-or-partial-views

Comment: Echo Jamie, just write a custom Html.IncludeJS helper extension.  Btw, javascript best practices dictates that you should stick scripts right before </body>.  This will allow your content to load faster, though you will have to deal with FOUC potentially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this question, best answer supposed to do what you need:
[ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor: Include js file in Head tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311783/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-include-js-file-in-head-tag)

Comment: That page is helpful for JS files, but it doesn't address CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about sounds like a custom helper similar to:

[Add CSS or JavaScript files to layout head from views or partial views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110028/add-css-or-js-files-to-layout-head-from-views-or-partial-views)