# Adding custom code/script into header files in ASP.net MVC 3 application?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC application and i'm trying to make one of the views display this [editable table](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html) and have server side code to actually support the javascript based editor with the appropriate callback functionality.

My first problem is that I need to add some custom javascript to the header of the view the table should appear in but it looks like the header is confined in _Layout.cshtml which means adding it there would make it in every view in the MVC app.

Anyone know how I can just add stuff to the header file only in the view controller I want it to be in?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311783/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-include-js-file-in-head-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need detail 
  In _layout.cshtml header section  add this line

```
   @RenderSection("HeaderJS",false)
```

In view use this section as follow

```
@section HeaderJS{
   // Write your script or css inclusion over here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Section in your Layout that's in the head.  The views can then add things to that section.  See ScottGu's discussion of this:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx