# Adding jquery to Empty MVC Project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly new to MVC and I'm trying to figure out how to add jquery to an empty MVC project.

I first added several js files to my project by installing several Nuget packages.  Then I added the following to my  my layout file.

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
</head>
```

Now when I run the project I get the following javascript error.

```
 JavaScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined
```

When am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: What browser you get that?

Comment: Take a look at these SO Questions:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197323/how-to-to-include-javascript-into-the-page-header-mvc4 & 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311783/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-include-js-file-in-head-tag These may help you sort out what you need/should be doing.

Comment: "JavaScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined" error might appear in old IE browsers. Take a look at Json2.js library

Answer (score 0):

In order to get MVC to recognize what the tilde means, you need to use:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
</head>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the newest version of jQuery that the jQuery Nuget packages installs drops support for IE 6, 7, and 8.  And also won't work in IE 9 or 10 if it loads in compatibility mode.

I added the following to my layout page to tell IE not to run in compatibility mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

It seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the head element of your cshtml or aspx:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

X-UA-Compatible meta tag allows web authors to choose which version of Internet Explorer the page should be rendered.