# Add scripts at the head of Aspx

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add some scripts at the head of a website, written in aspx. However, aspx pages do not have head part, but it is generated afterwards. how I can write something at the head of a website written in aspx?

Comment: What do you mean by that "they do not have head part"? You can simply put <script>SCRIPT GOES HERE</script> inside head tag in aspx pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tilda for your comment. I am using ASP.NET MVC4. There is a master page, but each file individually, has no a head part. I want to add something at the head part for a specific aspx page.

Comment: Hope this thread helps! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311783/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-include-js-file-in-head-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have a layout page that has a head part. In that render an optional section for your scripts.

In your layout file:

```
<head>
    ...
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</head>
```

And in your view in which you want to add scripts to the head part of the page do this:

```
@section scripts
{
   @Scripts.Render("~/YourScript.js")
}
```

Comment: @JimBlum ideally though you'd want to do that just before your `</body>` tag. Outside of modernizr, there usually isn't a reason to put scripts in the `head` tag.