# Cannot load resource MVC 4 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I need help with the below error. It cant seem to find the WarehouseJavascript.js file which is outside the scripts folder.

[image: error]

[image: ref]

Comment: ya that doesnt help either...

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062153/can-i-deploy-a-javascript-file-within-mvc-areas

Answer (score 0):

The URL `/Views/Warehouse/WareHouseJavascript.js` is invalid, because you have to make request to controller instead of view.

So you should do following:

1. Create controller for Warehouse it is not already exist (I cannot see it on your printscreen)
2. Create action method for above view
3. In action method return view  WareHouseJavascript
4. In link use `@Url.Action('Warehouse','Index')` assuming that controller name is `Warehouse` nad action is `Index`

Answer (score 0):

In your Views folder there should be a web.config file. In it, find the `system.web/httpHandlers` section, and a static file handler line before the wildcard 404 handler line per the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6453724/426894

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*.js" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```