# java script file 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

My `index.html` file from MVC application contains below code. All files get loaded into browser but no files from Views folder get loaded. 
`Index.html` file, Scripts & Views folders are located at root location.

```
   <body>
   <div ng-view></div>

        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="Views/Authentication/Services.js"></script> -- Error here
        <script src="Views/Authentication/AuthenticationController.js"></script> -- Error here

    </body>
```

Folder structure

[image]

I get below error message when I checked it from chrome devtool.

> `http://localhost:58348/Views/Authentication/AuthenticationController.js` 404 (Not Found)

Even I added `js/html` handler into web.config but still facing the same issue.

```
 <add name="JavaScriptHandler" path="*.js" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"
            type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />

          <add name="HtmlScriptHandler" path="*.html" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"
               type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
```

Comment: I think it is a problem with the path. `Scripts/Vies...` maybe?

Comment: are your scripts in the Views folder or the Scripts folder?

Comment: Index.html file, Scripts & Views folders are located at root location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refereed below post & my problem solved by adding web.config (with js/html handler) into view folder.

[Where to put view-specific javascript files in an ASP.NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604883/where-to-put-view-specific-javascript-files-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

The View might not be able to access the script file due to incorrect Path.

Try,

```
<script src="~/Views/Authentication/AuthenticationController.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Determine whether the **Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js** file is under WEB-INF
If it is in this file, change to its same level directory,
This may help