# Css in different folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make something like "templates system" it might allow user to change site template. In admin panel for example.

My current files structure

```
-Controllers
-Models
-Views
--Templates
---DefaultTemplate
----css
-----style.css
----Index.cshtml
```

In default controller (home) i check current template name and show right view

```
private ViewResult TemplateView(string viewName)
{
    return View($"~/Views/Templates/{GlobalSettings.CurrentTemplate}/{viewName}.cshtml");
}
```

And some template View (`Index.cshtml`)

```
.....
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Views/Templates/DefaultTemplate/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
.....
```

But I dont know how write correct path to my css\js\ images in right template forder.

I have tried

```
./css/style.css

@Url.Content("/css/style.css")
```

But in result HTML it is like `mysite.com/css/style.css` so i got 404 (not found)

I have also tried this

```
    ~/Views/Templates/DefaultTemplate/css/style.css
```

In this case i got 404 too.

So, can anybody help me? How to write correct URL to CSS, images, hs etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web.config file in the /Views folder restricts all access to files in the folder by default:

Add code to your web.config file:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Note: It's not good practice to store css files inside view folder.

Comment: Can i allow acces only for specified path? Not for all views folder?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604883/where-to-put-view-specific-javascript-files-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), but why you stored inside view folder?

Comment: User -friendliness. "Just put folder with views,css,js,images in templates folder and chose it in settings" - no need to put styles in "css/template", stripts in "js/template" etc.